# How do you redirect to another page from within the HTML view itself?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

The MVC View is a CART and sometimes it might have no items, for example when you clear the Cart itself.

My current code will display an empty Cart when NO items are present.

Instead I would like to redirect to the Home Page.

How can I redirect to the Home Page from within the MVC View itself?

Comment: For user-friendly pages I would suggest either displaying the cart page saying they dont have any items yet, or the homepage stating the same error to prevent confusion

Answer (score 1):

Can you show your code?
Judging by your description, make sure you return the RedirectToAction call.

```
return RedirectToAction(...);
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed the question cause the Controller is actually a [NonAction] ...so i'm happier if I can do the Redirect from within the View.

Comment: The controller is where you should check if the cart has 0 items and thus the place where you make the decision to redirect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663276/mvc3-redirect-from-a-nonaction-controller-event

Comment: Note: The controller is returning a TYPE and not an ActionResult and there is a lot of code written around, so that part cannot be changed (the return type of the controller)

Answer (score 1):

The concept in MVC there is no pages there's view's , for that manner you should not redirect but call/return another view like so:

for example you have HomeController and Index action the redirecting invoked like so...

```
public ActionResult LogOn() {
   .... 
  //return RedirectToAction("Index" , "Home");
  //return RedirectToRoute("the route you have signed in routes")
}
```

from View you do it like so;

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Index","Home")} //one way 

Or

@Html.ActionLink("Index","Home") //second way
```

Comment: for 1st option, I get this error: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments

for 2nd option, the home page renders inside the bottom of the current page

Comment: 1st) returns same exception, 2nd) just creates a link on the empty cart.