# MVC3 - Redirect from a [NonAction] Controller event

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Let's say I'm inside a [NonAction] controller event and would like to redirect out to the Home Page? What's the easiest way to do so?

```
[NonAction]
private ShoppingCartModel PrepareShoppingCartModel(ShoppingCartModel model, 
    IList<ShoppingCartItem> cart)
{
    if (cart == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("cart");

    if (model == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("model");

    if (cart.Count == 0)
        return model;

    ...bla bla bla (lots of code)     
 }
```

Now on the 3rd line, if the Cart.Count if = 0, instead of returning a empty model, that gets the View Display empty, I would rather redirect to the Home Page.

I cannot use return RedirectToAction() cause the compiler gives me the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult'
>   to 'Web.Models.ShoppingCart.ShoppingCartModel'

**QUESTION:**
So what's the right way to exit a [NonAction] Controller procedure?

Answer (score 0):

**Return type should be ActionResult** and **you should return View(model) instead of only model**. Your code should be like below.

```
[NonAction]
private ActionResult PrepareShoppingCartModel(ShoppingCartModel model, 
    IList<ShoppingCartItem> cart)
{
    if (cart == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("cart");

    if (model == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("model");

    if (cart.Count == 0)
        return View(model);

    ...bla bla bla (lots of code)     
 }
```

Comment: Well, that code is already written and I cannot just change it. There is a reason for returning a type instead of a ActionResult. I'm in need to know how to redirect from here ...instead of changing the "here" :--)